# Jquery - Send only some value from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, inputbox

using the checkTL() function, i need to send to the server (for example) only the input value into div with class "sideon". So, in the example, i need to get (server side) only the value of inputside0 and inputside3. How is possible this? 
cheers

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why are you requesting data in the form that you don't want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using AJAX?

```
<form method="POST" action="./index.php?general=example3" name="addtl">
    ...
</form>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('form[name=addtl]').submit(function() {
        var dataToPost = $(this).find('.sideon :input').serialize();
        $.post(this.action, dataToPost, function(result) {
            alert('success');    
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Of course putting input fields whose values shouldn't be submitted to the server into a form is doubtful. Maybe you should rethink the way you organize the forms.

Comment: in fact you are totally right! and you give to me a great solution. In fact i already move these div into other div! I can move them out to the main <form> :) I just to know how to move them into a div. I should use .append() right? tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

two ways:

1. make them into lots of seperate forms.
2. do `return false` on the form submit in jquery and use `$(".sideon").find('input').val();` to post an ajax query